# How to add noise into a standard distribution without increasing its variance?

Tags: normal-distribution, variance, noise, sum

Suppose I have a standard distribution dataset `X` with a mean 0 and std 1.

Now I want to create slight variations of this data by injecting some noise.

I could make a randomly generated noise `E` by sampling from normal distribution with a smaller std, let's say 0.1 then sum them together.

`Y = X + E`

While this does introduce the noise into the dataset, the variance would be the sum of their squared standard deviations. `Var(Y) = 1^2 + 0.1^2` which is not the same as the original distribution.

Hence the question, how do I inject some noise into the dataset but keep the original variance? (simply standardizing the outcome doesn't seem like a valid answer here)

Comment: What’s wrong with standardizing the outcome?

Comment: Well because aside from outliers that would make the original values smaller.

Comment: How do you figure you will add noise without changing the values?

Comment: Rather than making the original values smaller, roughly half would be smaller and the rest larger (assuming a symmetric error distribution).

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you want to add noise to your sample and what your desired outcome is for the resulting dataset?

Comment: This is to create image variations by introducing some noise into the latent space, example: https://ibb.co/album/t3WbMZ